# LOAD_HISTORY view is always empty

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The [LOAD_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/load_history.html) view never returns rows, even when using ACCOUNTADMIN role. The [COPY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html) function is showing data, however it has to be called separately per each table. And to determine a table for each pipe is a bit quirky...

Do I need any special permissions to use LOAD_HISTORY? 
What is the best way to monitor pipes/copy statements across whole db? I also do not want to use [COPY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/copy_history.html) view because of the delay.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the Information_Schema does depend on if you have [access to the object](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#general-usage-notes).  Do you need to use Information_Schema due to the latency or can you use [Account_Usage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/load_history.html) with ACCOUNTADMIN?  As you may know, there are some differences between the two outlined [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema), but you'll also want to check the Usage Notes for the particular view as some queries are not included (like if the query was rolled back).

COPY_HISTORY also has an information_schema [equivalent](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html) if this works for you.  I think this is the more popular view for monitoring Snowpipe.

Comment: yes latency (up to 4h) of account_usage views is not acceptable for monitoring purpose (a specially as there is now way of telling what the "current" latency is and when rows were "added" to the view). \Problem with COPY_HISTORY function is (as with whole information_schema) that it requires permissions on each table you want to monitor.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. One option is you could always run the function as ACCOUNTADMIN (who should ideally inherit all permissions) and populate the results into a table that is accessible by other roles.  You could even setup a task to do this so it's regularly updated.

Comment: But this seems a bit awkward and not very secure for monitoring job to run as an ACCOUNTADMIN. Is there no database/account/schema wide permissions allowing role to monitor (read from information_schema) all object within those?

Comment: I can understand that.  Here's another option if you'd like to give it a try (involves giving references, but I admit I haven't tried this with monitoring Snowpipe):  https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009F7v0tSAB/is-there-a-grant-permission-in-snowflake-which-is-equivalent-to-viewdefinition-in-sql-intent-is-make-a-particular-role-user-access-only-metadata-of-tables-but-not-permission-to-read-data-in-it-this-is-for-data-catalog

Comment: Thanks @suzy-lockwood. Giving references works, however it is still not ideal. I am trying to get some more feedback from snowflake support.